# How to remove background color from reply of html email template in Outlook 2010/2013

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I have created an html file that I converted into a outlook template file. My template has a solid blue background color that is defined by setting the bgcolor attribute on the body tag. When I send this to users everything is great until they reply using Outlook 2010 or 2013. When they reply the blue background color is present in their response. How can I write my css to only fill the background on the initial email, not the reply?

```
<body bgcolor="#0a3353"> 
<!-- Content tables -->
    <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#0a3353">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="container" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="70%" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                    <table class="container" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

I also noticed this behavior does not occur when using Outlook 2011 for mac.

Comment: try removing bgcolor from body. Keep it just on table.

Comment: @ImranBughio tried this but it doesn't fill the entire viewing area of the original email. It makes everything below the table white.

Comment: then make another table which covers the full area just don't use body tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a 100% width table in there instead of applying the background color to the body tag.

Here are the 2 setups I use that take control the forwarding background color (#FFFFFF), while setting the html section background (#252525).

**Fixed Width Email:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    /* Client-specific Styles */
    #outlook a {padding:0;}
    body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;} /* force default font sizes */
    .ExternalClass {width:100%;} .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;} /* Hotmail */
    a:active, a:visited, a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] { text-decoration: none; color: #000001 !important; pointer-events: auto; cursor: default;}
    table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
  </style>
</head>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><table bgcolor="#252525" width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td><table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td valign="top" style="padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px;">

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="white">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding:30px;">
      Content
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></body></html>
```

**Fluid Email:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    /* Client-specific Styles */
    #outlook a {padding:0;}
    body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;} /* force default font sizes */
    .ExternalClass {width:100%;} .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;} /* Hotmail */
    a:active, a:visited, a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] { text-decoration: none; color: #005288 !important; pointer-events: auto; cursor: default;}
    table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) { .maxW { width:600px !important; } }
  </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none;" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><table bgcolor="#252525" width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td valign="top">
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td valign="top">
<![endif]-->
<table width="100%" class="maxW" style="max-width: 600px; margin: auto;" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td valign="top" align="center" style="padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px;">


<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="margin: auto;">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" style="padding:30px;">
      Content
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


</td></tr></table>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
</td></tr></table>
<![endif]-->
</td></tr></table></body></html>
```

Comment: Excellent! I used the fluid email version and just added about 5% padding on the top and bottom of the inner table to make it fill out the background a bit better. Thanks a million!

Comment: I use the fluid almost exclusively these days. IMO fluid is the best technique for html email. It's 100% supported across major clients, while responsive isn't.